# pageinit does not exist on linux desktop browsers

Tags: jquery, linux, jquery-mobile, page-init

I recently developed a web app with jquery, which now needs to be consumed on mobile devices (ipad specifically).  I now added jquery mobile to the mix, and replace `click` with `tap`, which solved several issues.  I further went on and changed `ready` to `pageinit` - but this is where I hit a snag.

The old jquery code was:

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

This worked fine on desktop, but had some issues on mobile.  I changed that to

```
$(document).pageinit(function() { ... });
```

This worked fine on one of my dev machines (OS X) as well as on mobile.  However on my other dev machine (Ubuntu) I got error message `function pageinit does not exist`.  I then changed it to the "correct" way:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() { ... });
```

This doesn't work, as the function is never getting called.  I suspect this is because `onpageinit` event does not exist or something like that.  I further tried withe `pageshow`, `pagecreate`, etc. - the same result. Also the same result in Firefox and Chrome.

So, what am I missing here?  I now put in something like this in my code:

```
$doc = $(document);
func = $doc.pageinit ? $doc.pageinit : $doc.ready;
func(function() { ... });
```

which made it work on OS X, Ubuntu and iPad, but this feels/looks ugly.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: have tried assigning a specific page? `$(document).on('pageinit', '#page_id', function() { ... });`

Comment: @Omar Yes, tried that - the function doesn't get executed.